# Silverlight 4: Out of Browser, open new window?

Tags: silverlight, navigation, popup, window

I've googled like crazy but I can't find anything efficient regarding opening a new OOB window from an OOB silverlight 4 application.

I've found ways to manually initiate a web browser window to pop, but not another OOB silverlight child window that's NOT modal.

Apparently this functionality is in Silverlight 5 but as of now, upgrading from 4 to 5 is not a viable option.

Has anyone come up with any work-around or trick to do this?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to tweak/modify some of this code to come up with a solution:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/09/16/silverlight-out-of-browser-and-multiple-windows.aspx